# segue from UITableViewCell to UIViewController is not working (prepare for segue not called)

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiviewcontroller

I have a case that I need to show one specific UIViewController from different tab bar controllers, navigation controllers and acting by pressing table view cells and know where are from it was showed and run some code depending on that. So, I decided that the using of Storyboard Segue is nice idea, but even can't call prepare for segue function. All using show segue identifiers are named, so I don't know what's wrong I'm doing.

But if somebody want to say any other ways to implement some kind of it, i want to know it.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/BqeUX.jpg

I'm trying to do it though Storyboard References (just cuz it looks easier to navigate in storyboard), but connection directly to the UIViewController isn't works too.

I'm on Xcode 10.1 and Swift 4.2.1

```
 import UIKit

 class TestsController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }


    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        print("I'm working!'")
        if segue.identifier == "Test1" {
            print("test 1")
        } else if segue.identifier == "Test2" {
            print("test 2")
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A static table can only be inside a `UITableViewController` , so change

```
class TestsController: UITableViewController {
```

then assign this class in IB , and remove any implementations of the `UITableView` | `UITableViewDelegate` | `UITableViewDataSource`

then prepare should work , look to this [Demo](https://www.mediafire.com/file/4rp2g66gol20k42/jhjhjkjjk.zip/file)

Comment: Ah, got it, the prepare for segue should be in View from which we shows, but not the one that we want to show. Ok, now I have to come up with some other solution to the my case. Thanks for help!